# CMN_1022 Database driver error... CMN_1022 [ [Informatica][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver]Connection refused

Tags: oracle, informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

Team, I am getting this error in `informatica` cloud when i run the mapping.Oracle is running properly, `informatica` connection is working properly still throw this error..
I have attached the screensort.

```
error--- CMN_1022 Database driver error... CMN_1022 [ [Informatica][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver]Connection refused. Verify Host Name and Port Number.[Informatica][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]ORA-12203: unable to connect to destination Database driver error... Function Name : Connect Database driver error... Function Name : Connect Database Error: Failed to connect to database using user [core] and connection string [Driver=DataDirect CLOSED 8.0 Oracle Wire Protocol for Informatica - BASE;Host=localhost;ServiceName=xe;Port=1521;UID=core;AS=6000000;EBL=0;ENS=1;IACP=4;ETWT=1;WorkArounds
```

it must be run as my database and `informatica` connection is working properly.
Please help on this to get it fixed.

Comment: Why do you think your Oracle connection is working properly when the error message is explicitly stating that it isn’t?

Comment: Error is explicitely saying that it cannot connect. Port looks fine, but please double check the Host=localhost...

Answer (score 0):

Missing TNS entry in tnsnames.ora file. Same happens to SQL connections if host details are missing in ODBC.ini file

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35496258)